# AWS EKS CNI Creating Duplicate Network Interfaces Causing Outages

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I'm running an EKS cluster on AWS and I've been having periodic outages recently. I tracked down the issue to duplicate network interfaces on one of my nodes, which I believe are created by the [AWS CNI plugin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-networking.html).

When the node is created, it has 2 NICs. But at some point later in the node's life, a 3rd NIC is created (not by me) which causes strange behavior. It looks like the `rp_filter` is rejecting packets from the ELB as the SYN packet shows up in the `messages` log as a martian.

I should add that this only seems to happen for services that are annotated as `service.beta.kubernetes.io/external-traffic: OnlyLocal`

When I detach the 3rd NIC, everything returns to normal.

My questions are

1. Why might the 3rd NIC cause this problem? Is this a bug in CNI?
2. How can I workaround this issue?

   1. Is there some way I can prevent the 3rd NIC from being attached?
   2. Is there some way to [configure CNI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-env-vars.html) so that it attaches the 3rd NIC correctly? Do I have EKS configured incorrectly somehow?

Some evidence:

`netstat -s` is showing `IPReversePathFilter: 666179` and increments by one for every SYN from the ELB exactly.

`tail /var/log/messages` shows the martian packets like so

```
Nov 22 18:37:17 ip-192-168-90-83 kernel: IPv4: martian source 192.168.102.150 from 192.168.236.246, on dev eth0
Nov 22 18:37:17 ip-192-168-90-83 kernel: ll header: 00000000: 0e 76 b3 cc 10 f4 0e 6f 51 60 fa be 08 00        .v.....oQ`....
```

When I set `rp_filter=0`, then the SYN from the ELB isn't dropped anymore and I see the SYN-ACKs head toward the ELB, but they never make it there.